# XML reponses in php

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

I am working with a SOAP API that no matter how I try I am unable to get it working with PHP ( I was told by others working with this API that they were not able to get it working with any other language other than Perl which is what it is written in). I had to "hack" a bit so PHP could handle it correctly.

The code I am using is:

```
    <?PHP
$uid = 'username';
$pass = 'password';
$customer_xml = my_api($uid, $pass, 'get_numbers', 'number', 'contains', '1', '0', '0');

function my_api($user, $pass, $func, $request_args){

    $soap = new SoapClient("admin/enswitch_3.9.wsdl", array('trace' => true, 'exceptions' => false));
    $result1 = $soap->$func($user,$pass,$request_args);

    if(isset($soap->__soap_fault)){
            echo 'There was an error connecting via SOAP. Below is the error:';
            print_r($soap->__soap_fault->faultstring);
            }
    elseif(isset($soap->__last_response)){

            echo "Unedited soap response is:\n";
            echo $soap->__last_response."\n";
            echo "\n\n";

            $xml_string = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $soap->__last_response);
            //We need to replace the text s-gensym and then the number with some random text
            //like xoxo so we can then get the value of $xml->response->xoxo which should be an array
            $xml_string = preg_replace('/s-gensym[0-9]{0,65000}/', 'xoxo', $xml_string);

            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string);


            $xml = $xml->soapBody;
            $func_response = $func.'Response';

            echo '$xml->$func_response is'."\n";
            print_r($xml->$func_response);
            echo "\n\n";

            echo '$xml->$func_response->xoxo is'."\n";
            print_r( $xml->$func_response->xoxo);
            die();

            return $xml->$func_response->xoxo;
            }
    }
?>
```

The response that I get from my script code is (phone numbers have been changed to protect them):

```
Unedited soap response is:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><get_numbersResponse xmlns="http://www.example.com/Integrics/Enswitch/API"><s-gensym3><maximum_seconds xsi:type="xsd:string">-1</maximum_seconds><direct xsi:type="xsd:string">1</direct><fax_dtype xsi:type="xsd:string">hangup</fax_dtype><stype xsi:type="xsd:string">number</stype><emergency_register xsi:type="xsd:string">0</emergency_register><directory xsi:type="xsd:string">1</directory><display xsi:type="xsd:string">12125550432</display><sname_action xsi:type="xsd:string">replace</sname_action><shared xsi:type="xsd:string">0</shared><callerid xsi:type="xsd:string" /><dtype xsi:type="xsd:string">queue</dtype><sname xsi:type="xsd:string" /><dnumber xsi:type="xsd:string">696</dnumber><fax_detect xsi:type="xsd:string">0</fax_detect><music xsi:type="xsd:string">0</music><update_routing xsi:type="xsd:string">1</update_routing><routing xsi:type="xsd:string" /><owner xsi:type="xsd:string">0</owner><ported xsi:type="xsd:string">0</ported><language xsi:type="xsd:string">en</language><fax_dnumber xsi:type="xsd:string" /><description xsi:type="xsd:string" /><ingroup xsi:type="xsd:string">12</ingroup><play_message xsi:type="xsd:string">0</play_message><screen xsi:type="xsd:string">0</screen><customer xsi:type="xsd:string">3935</customer><recordgroup xsi:type="xsd:string">0</recordgroup><class xsi:type="xsd:string">212</class><shortcut xsi:type="xsd:string">1</shortcut><alias xsi:type="xsd:string" /><snumber xsi:type="xsd:string">12125550432</snumber></s-gensym3><s-gensym5><maximum_seconds xsi:type="xsd:string">-1</maximum_seconds><direct xsi:type="xsd:string">1</direct><fax_dtype xsi:type="xsd:string">hangup</fax_dtype><stype xsi:type="xsd:string">number</stype><emergency_register xsi:type="xsd:string">0</emergency_register><directory xsi:type="xsd:string">1</directory><display xsi:type="xsd:string">12125550458 TEST FOR COLLECT CALL DISABLING</display><sname_action xsi:type="xsd:string">replace</sname_action><shared xsi:type="xsd:string">0</shared><callerid xsi:type="xsd:string" /><dtype xsi:type="xsd:string">forward</dtype><sname xsi:type="xsd:string" /><dnumber xsi:type="xsd:string">18005551212</dnumber><fax_detect xsi:type="xsd:string">0</fax_detect><music xsi:type="xsd:string">0</music><update_routing xsi:type="xsd:string">0</update_routing><routing xsi:type="xsd:string" /><owner xsi:type="xsd:string">0</owner><ported xsi:type="xsd:string">0</ported><language xsi:type="xsd:string">en</language><fax_dnumber xsi:type="xsd:string" /><description xsi:type="xsd:string">TEST FOR COLLECT CALL DISABLING</description><ingroup xsi:type="xsd:string">12</ingroup><play_message xsi:type="xsd:string">0</play_message><screen xsi:type="xsd:string">0</screen><customer xsi:type="xsd:string">3935</customer><recordgroup xsi:type="xsd:string">0</recordgroup><class xsi:type="xsd:string">212</class><shortcut xsi:type="xsd:string">1</shortcut><alias xsi:type="xsd:string" /><snumber xsi:type="xsd:string">12125550458</snumber></s-gensym5></get_numbersResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

$xml->$func_response is
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [xoxo] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [maximum_seconds] => -1
                [direct] => 1
                [fax_dtype] => hangup
                [stype] => number
                [emergency_register] => 0
                [directory] => 1
                [display] => 12125550432
                [sname_action] => replace
                [shared] => 0
                [callerid] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [dtype] => queue
                [sname] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [dnumber] => 696
                [fax_detect] => 0
                [music] => 0
                [update_routing] => 1
                [routing] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [owner] => 0
                [ported] => 0
                [language] => en
                [fax_dnumber] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [ingroup] => 12
                [play_message] => 0
                [screen] => 0
                [customer] => 3935
                [recordgroup] => 0
                [class] => 212
                [shortcut] => 1
                [alias] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [snumber] => 12125550432
            )

        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [maximum_seconds] => -1
                [direct] => 1
                [fax_dtype] => hangup
                [stype] => number
                [emergency_register] => 0
                [directory] => 1
                [display] => 12125550458 TEST FOR COLLECT CALL DISABLING
                [sname_action] => replace
                [shared] => 0
                [callerid] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [dtype] => forward
                [sname] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [dnumber] => 18005551212
                [fax_detect] => 0
                [music] => 0
                [update_routing] => 0
                [routing] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [owner] => 0
                [ported] => 0
                [language] => en
                [fax_dnumber] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )
                [description] => TEST FOR COLLECT CALL DISABLING
                [ingroup] => 12
                [play_message] => 0
                [screen] => 0
                [customer] => 3935
                [recordgroup] => 0
                [class] => 212
                [shortcut] => 1
                [alias] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )
                [snumber] => 12125550458
            )
    )
)
$xml->$func_response->xoxo is
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[maximum_seconds] => -1
[direct] => 1
[fax_dtype] => hangup
[stype] => number
[emergency_register] => 0
[directory] => 1
[display] => 12125550432
[sname_action] => replace
[shared] => 0
[callerid] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[dtype] => queue
[sname] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[dnumber] => 696
[fax_detect] => 0
[music] => 0
[update_routing] => 1
[routing] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[owner] => 0
[ported] => 0
[language] => en
[fax_dnumber] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[ingroup] => 12
[play_message] => 0
[screen] => 0
[customer] => 3935
[recordgroup] => 0
[class] => 212
[shortcut] => 1
[alias] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[snumber] => 12125550432
)
```

My question is how come $xml->$func_response will show multiple responses under "element" xoxo but if I try to print_r on $xml->func_response->xoxo I only get one response. Interesting enough if I do:

```
    foreach($xml->func_response as $y){
        foreach($y as $z){
          print_r($z)
          }
         }
        }
```

Then I do get the value for each one but it seems backward to do it that way.

---

#### Reformatted XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <get_numbersResponse xmlns="http://www.example.com/Integrics/Enswitch/API">
            <s-gensym3>
                <maximum_seconds xsi:type="xsd:string">-1</maximum_seconds>
                <direct xsi:type="xsd:string">1</direct>
                <fax_dtype xsi:type="xsd:string">hangup</fax_dtype>
                <stype xsi:type="xsd:string">number</stype>
                <emergency_register xsi:type="xsd:string">0</emergency_register>
                <directory xsi:type="xsd:string">1</directory>
                <display xsi:type="xsd:string">12125550432</display>
                <sname_action xsi:type="xsd:string">replace</sname_action>
                <shared xsi:type="xsd:string">0</shared>
                <callerid xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                <dtype xsi:type="xsd:string">queue</dtype>
                <sname xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                <dnumber xsi:type="xsd:string">696</dnumber>
                <fax_detect xsi:type="xsd:string">0</fax_detect>
                <music xsi:type="xsd:string">0</music>
                <update_routing xsi:type="xsd:string">1</update_routing>
                <routing xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                <owner xsi:type="xsd:string">0</owner>
                <ported xsi:type="xsd:string">0</ported>
                <language xsi:type="xsd:string">en</language>
                <fax_dnumber xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                <description xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                <ingroup xsi:type="xsd:string">12</ingroup>
                <play_message xsi:type="xsd:string">0</play_message>
                <screen xsi:type="xsd:string">0</screen>
                <customer xsi:type="xsd:string">3935</customer>
                <recordgroup xsi:type="xsd:string">0</recordgroup>
                <class xsi:type="xsd:string">212</class>
                <shortcut xsi:type="xsd:string">1</shortcut>
                <alias xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                <snumber xsi:type="xsd:string">12125550432</snumber>
            </s-gensym3>
            <s-gensym5>
                <maximum_seconds xsi:type="xsd:string">-1</maximum_seconds>
                <direct xsi:type="xsd:string">1</direct>
                <fax_dtype xsi:type="xsd:string">hangup</fax_dtype>
                <stype xsi:type="xsd:string">number</stype>
                <emergency_register xsi:type="xsd:string">0</emergency_register>
                <directory xsi:type="xsd:string">1</directory>
                <display xsi:type="xsd:string">12125550458 TEST FOR COLLECT CALL DISABLING</display>
                <sname_action xsi:type="xsd:string">replace</sname_action>
                <shared xsi:type="xsd:string">0</shared>
                <callerid xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                <dtype xsi:type="xsd:string">forward</dtype>
                <sname xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                <dnumber xsi:type="xsd:string">18005551212</dnumber>
                <fax_detect xsi:type="xsd:string">0</fax_detect>
                <music xsi:type="xsd:string">0</music>
                <update_routing xsi:type="xsd:string">0</update_routing>
                <routing xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                <owner xsi:type="xsd:string">0</owner>
                <ported xsi:type="xsd:string">0</ported>
                <language xsi:type="xsd:string">en</language>
                <fax_dnumber xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                <description xsi:type="xsd:string">TEST FOR COLLECT CALL DISABLING</description>
                <ingroup xsi:type="xsd:string">12</ingroup>
                <play_message xsi:type="xsd:string">0</play_message>
                <screen xsi:type="xsd:string">0</screen>
                <customer xsi:type="xsd:string">3935</customer>
                <recordgroup xsi:type="xsd:string">0</recordgroup>
                <class xsi:type="xsd:string">212</class>
                <shortcut xsi:type="xsd:string">1</shortcut>
                <alias xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                <snumber xsi:type="xsd:string">12125550458</snumber>
            </s-gensym5>
        </get_numbersResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Why have you had to change the XML like that? What happens if you leave the `preg_replace` calls out?

Comment: This doesn't really look like a `perl` question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason why, just because SOAP interface was implemented in Perl, you need to use Perl to write your SOAP client

You don't explain why you're removing the namespaces, or changing all of the `s-gensym*` elements to `xoxo` but it isn't necessary

There is one gotcha: if you want to use a non-blank namespace in an XPath expression then you have to *name* a prefix and *use* it in your code. The element

```
<get_numbersResponse xmlns="http://www.example.com/Integrics/Enswitch/API"> ... </get_numbersResponse>
```

has a blank default namespace, so I have bound the prefix `def` to it in my code below so that it can now be referred to as `def:get_numbersResponse`. Apart from that you can simply navigate the XML data using XPath expressions. The `soap` namespace prefix is already defined by the XML, so I can refer to `soap:Envelope` and `soap:Body` without defining it in my code

You don't say what data you want, but I have extracted the `display` field from both `s-gensym3` and `s-gensym5`. And my code reads the XML from the file `soap.xml`; I assume you can use this code to work with the data from your SOAP client object?

```
<?php

  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('soap.xml', NULL, TRUE);
  $xml->registerXPathNamespace('def', 'http://www.example.com/Integrics/Enswitch/API');
  $numbers_response = $xml->xpath('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/def:get_numbersResponse/*');

  while (list($i, $node) = each($numbers_response)) {
    print("\n");
    printf("%d: %s\n", $i, $node->getName());
    printf("    %s\n", $node->display);
  }
?>
```

#### output

```
0: s-gensym3
    12125550432

1: s-gensym5
    12125550458 TEST FOR COLLECT CALL DISABLING
```

Comment: The special handling for the default namespace you mention is not a limitation of LibXML, but of XPath 1.0, which has no notion of default namespace (nor does it implicitly inherit prefixes from the target document, IIRC). If you're not using XPath, you don't need to call `registerXPathNamespace`; for instance, if you use `$xml->children('http://example.com/namespace/uri')->something->child->etc['attribute']`.

Comment: 1) I posted here because I am a n00b with SOAP APi's and name spaces.
2) I have no problem getting the info into an array. The issue is getting the data in a way that I can use it in my code. For instance if I use a while loop it wont work as PHP see's it as one array (because s-gensym3 and s-genym5 are not unique.

If it looked something like this (which is the result that I want) then it would be very work able:
###output

    0: 12125550432
    
    1: 12125550458 TEST FOR COLLECT CALL DISABLING

Comment: @DovidBender: I thought I had shown you how to do that

Comment: @Borodin After playing a bit more I figured it out. Thanks for the help.